# Why a piped command to tee didn't work properly and didn't return?

Tags: bash, go, pipe, tee

I have a Go application inserting data in a DB and also writing something to `os.Stdout` using the package `logrus`. For each DB insertion, a log is written to stdout.

Here is the command I use `goapp | tee myfile`

I found out that the `goapp` correctly inserted data in the DB for hours BUT the file was empty and it didn't show anything in stdout.
At one point it stopped the insertion for some reason (I don't know).

- The app was stuck waiting for stdout's buffer or something
- Somehow maybe tee didn't start or has crashed

If `tee` crashed why `goapp` didn't crash when it tries to write to stdout?! It should at least receive a `SIGPIPE`.

This command has worked correctly for weeks. It's the first time it fails so badly and I'm lost on the reason. I'm not so confident in using stdout with tee anymore if it isn't reliable.

The go code is very straightforward:

```golang
import "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"

func NewLogger(outputFile *os.File) *logrus.Logger {
    var log = logrus.New()
    log.Formatter = new(logrus.JSONFormatter)
    log.Level = logrus.TraceLevel
    log.Out = outputFile
    return log
}
logger := NewLogger(os.Stdout)

for {
[...]
err = InsertInDatabase(db, databaseArgs)
logger.Traceln("inserted in the database")
[...]
}
```

Do I miss something? What can be the reason? The fact that data was inserted in the DB but not logged to stdout makes me think there was something wrong with the pipe and tee.

Comment: I guess logrus, by default outputs to stderr instead of stdout

Comment: It has always worked but that time (not a starter question), the line `log.Out = outputFile` sets the output to `os.Stdout`.

Comment: One alternate way to avoid `tee` becoming a child process of shell, but only wait only for your golang app termination, would be to use process substitution, i.e. `goapp > >(tee myfile)`. There is a possibility in your OP, that your app died and `tee` was not terminated properly

Comment: What is "OP"? Thank you for the alternative, I've seen it as an answer in a similar question (but using the file as input and output). I still would like to understand how is it possible that tee wasn't terminated if my app crashed? Too bad I didn't check `ps aux` to know which one crashed...

Comment: (original post)

Comment: Sorry, now I think I see why the whole command didn't return even though `goapp` crashed. (Should we never use tee with a pipe?!) But it doesn't explain why tee didn't write anything in the file+stdout at the beginning for few hours until goapp completely stopped working.

Comment: Also one other recommendation - Try running your pipeline with `set -e; set -o pipefail` to cause one failed command to exit the whole

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try all the solutions hoping I can reproduce the issue.

Comment: `set -e` is dangerous: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105 might exit even when the command returns !=0 value when successful.